# Detecting a DIV that is mostly in the viewport/center as you scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to know when an element is most visible in the viewport and is mostly in the center. I'd like to have all the other divs fade off but keeping the more dominant DIV at full opacity as you scroll.

I found this: http://patik.com/code/within-viewport/ but it's by pixel and doesn't have the logic I require for this to work like in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Sure. You can use jquery to mangle a DOM structure any way you want.

Comment: Do what? Please clarify the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I add more clarification and added some research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a method that tested whether an element was fully within the bounds of the page. There are plugins that do this such as Remy Sharp's [Element in-view Event Plugin](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/) or [this by Digital Fusion](http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-element-onscreen-visibility/194/) but essentially you just need to test if an element is fully in view and add a class to it.

All relatively simple (although I confess to have not tested this x-browser so YMMV):

```
function testInView($el){
    var wTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var wBot = wTop + $(window).height();
    var eTop = $el.offset().top;
    var eBot = eTop + $el.height();
    return ((eBot <= wBot) && (eTop >= wTop));
}
function setInView(){
    $("div").each(function(){//testing EVERY div (you might want to be more specific in your implementation)
        var $zis = $(this);
        $zis.removeClass("inview");
        if(testInView($zis)){
           $zis.addClass("inview");   
        }
    });
}
$(document).scroll(function(){
    setInView();
});
$(document).resize(function(){
    setInView();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInView();
});
```

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moob/4RXYG/)

Comment: sure, use JQuery, because the native implementation is lame.... ( i am just being mean )

Comment: @helly0d - I agree with your sentiment. I was just being lazy in using jQuery ;)

Comment: This is amazing... thank you. I couldn't wrap my head around the logic of finding each div's position relative to scroll, but knowing which DIV was mostly inview. Thank you.

Comment: Ah the only problem I found with this solution is there is a slight gap where nothing is being added the 'inview' class.

Comment: i really love the path that SO got to.... ScriptKiddies for the win. How can i do this? ( with no effort shown ) Here's how... ( 20 points rep gained ) But when you actually give them just a hint so that they will learn something from it all you get is a downvote ( OMG this noob doesn't know that i need za code not another wikipedia answer )

Comment: @helly0d I upvoted you, I'm just reading about `getBoundingClientRect`. Pretty awesome stuff, thanks!

Comment: @Tom - at some points there may be no single element that its FULLY in view. You could perform extra tests to determin which of the elements is the *most* in view or you could take the easy way out as [I have here](http://jsfiddle.net/moob/4RXYG/2/) and just add an offset that allows the element to be so many pixels outside of the bounds.

Comment: @moob I think the biggest problem now is because we are reading the height and top of the DIV, if the DIV is longer than the window, this won't work.

Comment: @Tom You could adapt the script to check whether the element is over the mid-point of the page E.G http://jsfiddle.net/moob/4RXYG/7/

Answer (score 1):

Over the scroll event you can test each div in the container if it has the bounding rectangle ( use `getBoundingClientRect` function over each div from container ) in the required zone. Also here you can test to see how much of this rectangle is visible by some simple formulas, and set the opacity accordingly.