# jQuery 2.1 | Highlight first <li> completely visible in scrollable <ol> viewport

Tags: jquery, html-lists, viewport

I'm trying to adapt [this code from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304079/detecting-a-div-that-is-mostly-in-the-viewport-center-as-you-scroll) for my specific needs. I need to highlight via `addClass` the first `<li>` that is completely visible in a scrolling `<ol>` viewport, regardless of length of `<li>`. I swapped the `$(window)` scrolling part of the code for a scrollable `<ol>` which nearly does the job but results in offset issues after exceeding an `<li>` length because the `<li>` are smaller in height than the parent `<ol>` height :

```
function testInView($el){
    var wTop = $('#OL').scrollTop() / 6; // Updated
    var wBot = wTop + $('#OL').height();
    var eTop = $el.offset().top;
    var eBot = eTop + $el.height();
    return ((eBot <= wBot) && (eTop >= wTop));
}
function setInView(){
    $("li").each(function(){
        var $zis = $(this);
        $zis.removeClass("inview");
        if(testInView($zis)){
           $zis.addClass("inview");
        }
    });
$('#OL').find('.inview:first').next().next().addClass(".higlight"); // Updated
}

$('#OL').scroll(function(){
    setInView();
});
```

My `<ol>` makes visible six `<li>` of 80px each in height when scrolling, therefore my `<ol>` is 480px in height. How can the above code be edited to work with these heights regardless of amount of `<li>` length, or better yet, can the code be written to dynamically adapt to any `<li>` and/or `<ol>` heights?

**UPDATE 1**

I amended the above code (see comments) :

```
var wTop = $('#OL').scrollTop() / 6; // Added devide by 6

...

$('#OL').find('.inview:first').next().next().addClass(".higlight");
// Added two next()
```

The above edits enable highlighting in a more stable manner the `<li>` targets, however, as `<li>` length grows, `.highlight` targets the bottom-most `<li>` and does not apply at all when `<li>` length exceeds 38. The edits act more like a hack than a solid solution, any hints on cleaner efficient code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 2 - FINAL**

This [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919245/how-to-get-the-first-dom-element-that-is-visible-in-a-viewport) provides "*cleaner efficient code*" that I modified for use as basis of answer for my above question :

```
function setInView(){

var scroll = $('ol:visible').scrollTop() / 1000; // See Note below
var elements = $('ol:visible').find('li');
var el;

   for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    elements.css('border-color',''); // Erase color with css
        el = $(elements[i]);
        if (el.offset().top >= scroll && el.is(':visible')){
            // "el" is the first visible element here!
            // Do something fancy with it
            el.next().next().css('border-color','#F00');
            // Quit the loop
            break;
        }
    }
}

$('ol').scroll(function(){
setInView();
});
```

**Note**: `<ol>` visibility selector ensures this function only targets scrollable ordered lists that are made visible. Dividing by 1000+ ensures lists of `<li>` length of 600+ will be targeted correctly by the function. I used css color swaps as they were faster to handle than classes for my application.